# Visibility modifier conflict in interface declaration in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, interface

I have a simple recycler view where I have Interface within the body and I have declared the interface in constructor parameter so I can access it within the recycler view's body. But it shows the error as

```
Conflicting declarations: public interface CardClickListener, private final val CardClickListener: MemoryBoardAdapter.CardClickListener
```

I have tried to change the visibility modifiers but still the error persists.
**
My Code:**

**Recycler View With Interface:**

```
class MemoryBoardAdapter(   private val CardClickListener: CardClickListener ) :     RecyclerView.Adapter<MemoryBoardAdapter.ViewHolder>() { 

interface CardClickListener{     

    fun onCardClicked(position: Int) 

    } }
```

**MainActivity object calling the recyclerView:**

```
binding.rvBoard.adapter = MemoryBoardAdapter(object: MemoryBoardAdapter.CardClickListener{override fun onCardClicked(position: Int) {// TODO}

        })
```

I tried to change from private val to internal var but still the error persists. if I remove the visibility modifier in the class constructor the error goes away but I cant access the interface within the class body.

Comment: use camelCase for your variable name (or just not the same name as your static nested interface).

Comment: @Mark Yup that solved. Thank you for your time. Sorry for a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The capital C for CardClickListener in `object: MemoryBoardAdapter.CardClickListener` is conflicting with the interface name `CardClickListener` inside your adapter. Change the name of the parameter or use **cardClickListener**

```
class MemoryBoardAdapter(private val cardClickListener: CardClickListener )
```

instead of

```
class MemoryBoardAdapter(private val CardClickListener: CardClickListener )
```